# Is this a fossil?

Tags: fossil

My neighbor found this rock and asked for help identifying it as a fossil. Can anyone confirm that it is/isn't a fossil? If it is, what it is a fossil of?

It was found near Lexington, VA, USA, on Short Mountain. It is about 12cm long, 8cm wide and 6cm tall.

[image: Pic 1]

[image: Pic 2]

[image]

Comment: City's you please edit your post and add the size of the object and roughly were in the world it was found?

Comment: @Arsak Done - I had to approximate the size as I don't have it anymore, but the estimate is probably close enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

It bears no halmarks or indicators of being a fossil, and it does not look like any fossil I have ever seen . it looks like simple chemical weathering.